# If 2 people pay 10 each, how much would a 3rd person have to pay to have an equal share?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If person 1 and 2 pay $\$10$ to equal $\$20$, how much would person 3 have to pay person 1 and 2 to become even?

My solution: 20 divided by 3 is 6.66 so wouldn't the 3rd person just have to pay each person $\$3.33$? This way everybody pays $\$6.66$. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: "To become even"?  Do you mean the two things should both equal $20?

Answer (score 1):

Since money can't be more than two places after the decimal point, it's not even, but you're close since ${$6.66\cdot3=$19.98}$, which is exactly two cents away with a good idea for rounding down.  It's just not enough money.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply! I'm not worried about the two cents, Maybe I should have put it this way:

So if two people temporarily covered the cost of \$20 for the 3rd person by paying \$10 each, how much would the 3rd person owe person 1 and 2? ( so that everyone is paying the same amount in the end.)

Comment: This answer is a comment on the answer given by ReliableMathBoy.  Rather than posting it as an answer, you should click "add a comment" and post it there.